# scope of classes

Tags: c++

```
class a
{
  private:
    b *b_obj;
  public:
    void set(int);
};

a::a()
{
  b_obj = new b;
}

a::set(int s)
{
  b_obj->c = s;
 }

class b
{
  public:
    int c;
};
```

is this code valid?
if no, how do i make b_obj of a particular object (say a_obj) of class a ,modifiable in another class c...if a_obj i created in another class d....i am scared of a_obj going out of scope in class c.

hope you understand my question.
thanks a lot for taking the time to read my post

Comment: Maybe one single, specific question at a time, together with a coherent, small code example, will encourage better answers...

Comment: Voting to close as "Not a real question". @CAD_Coding, crystallise your thoughts until you have until individual questions that are detailed and specific, then ask those questions, or just ask your "finally " question. Hope this helps.

Comment: @BinaryWorrier can u plz answer my "finally" question then?

Comment: Agreed with close.  There's a question here somewhere, I just can't really find it.

Comment: If you can narrow this down to a single, answerable question, I'd be happy to re-open it for you.

Comment: @CAD_coding Head over to [the C++ FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/) and read 7 & 10-12 for starters. This should answer a lot of your questions and help you narrow any resulting SO questions.

Comment: @CAD_coding That's quite a bit better.

Comment: Much better.  Now I can answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is *nearly* valid.  `class b` needs to be declared (or at least forward declared) before it is referred to in `class a`, you do not specify the return type in the definition for `a::set`, and you have not provided a declaration for `a`'a default constructor.  Here is the revised code, along with a test harness:

```
class b
{
  public:
    int c;
};

class a
{
  private:
    b *b_obj;
  public:
    a();
    void set(int);
};

a::a()
{
  b_obj = new b;
}

void a::set(int s)
{
  b_obj->c = s;
}

int main()
{
    a my_a;
    my_a.set(42);
}
```

Now, just because the code is *valid* doesn't mean it's *good*:

1. You don't initialize `c` when default-constructing `b`.
2. You use raw pointers to dyanamically-allocated `b`'s.  Use automatic variables instead, whenever possible.  Among the the reasons for this are ...
3. You never `delete` the `b` you `new`'ed in `a`'a constructor.  This results in a memory leak.  If you had avoided the use of dynamic allocation in the first place, this would not be an issue.

Comment: thanks a lot!!!! :)
your test is exactly what i wanted to say + 1 more thing i need to ask:
in main() if i use:

printf("\n%d\n", b_obj->get());//get() returns c

i use delete b_obj in the destructor of class b...
so will the above printf print 42 or will it go out of scope?

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing the actual code, but if I understand what you're asking then yes.  Why dobn't you try it yourself & find out?

Answer (score 0):

Well,

```
*b_obj = *other_b_obj;// equality of objects values
b_obj = other_b_obj; // equality for pointer values
```

assuming that `b_obj` is an object and `other_b_obj` is a pointer:

```
b_obj = *other_b_obj;
```

Assuming the reverse:

```
b_obj = &other_b_obj;
```

Assuming both are pointers:

```
b_obj = other_b_obj;
```

for your final question, `new` is not compulsory for assgining pointers. A pointer may point to an exiting object. However, if you want the pointer to point to a new object, use then `new` keyword, which attempts to create new object and returns the new object address.

Comment: Still incorrect.  As far as we can tell there is nothing invalid about `*b_obj = *other_b_obk` other than it being plain bad coding.

Comment: b_obj is a pointer to an object of class b.
is it necessary to create an object of b for using b_obj?
is other_b_obj valid?@JohnDibling

Comment: This answer now bears no resemblance to what you originally said.

Comment: @CAD:  Don't try to game the system.  Spend some time & effort trying to construct a cohesive question, and I will answer that.

Comment: @JohnDibling is my question understandable now?
may be my language is not so good...i am extremely sorry for that... but please do consider that i am a mech engg student & i am too inquisitive to learn c++ under the pressure of mech engg!

Comment: Note that the question has changed, significantly.

Answer (score 0):

> is this code valid?

The code is *almost* valid, except that you forgot to state the return type of the set function:

```
void a::set(int s)
```

However, the set function will really change the `c` member of `b_obj`. It is public, so the compiler will allow it.

[BTW, why don't you try for yourself?](http://ideone.com/4uDnE)

As an aside, while you're studying, look at constructors, destructors, assignment operator and implement them to free the object `b_obj` properly. You can even use a `shared_ptr` for that.

Also, I wouldn't advise you to use such a dull name as lowercase `a` for a class.

Comment: thanks for the ideone link...i didnt know that...thanks a lot